# How to choose between Poisson and Poisson random effect model?

Tags: r, likelihood, poisson-regression

I have fitted both a Poisson random effect and Poisson classical model (i.e., pooled Poisson model) to my data, however some of the estimates are of different signs and SE are quite similar for both of the models. The log likelihood for the Poisson random is -669.723 and that of Poisson model is -756.396. How can I determine which model to choose?

Poisson classic and random effects regression models

```
             Poisson Classical Model         Poisson random-effects model

          Estimate    SE    z value          Estimate      SE    z value

Intercept 0.81345  0.14438    5.634          -0.12224   0.46203  -0.265
make 2    -0.3677  0.20552   -1.789           -0.4753   0.20696  -2.297
make 3    -0.1502  0.21120   -0.711          -0.31749   0.21425  -1.482
make 4    -0.4758  0.13438   -3.541          -0.29236   0.14085  -2.076
agevehO   -0.2041  0.08613   -2.370           0.02868   0.09034   0.318
maritalUM -0.8184  0.12471   -6.563           0.34105   0.20314   1.679
insageOL  -0.3309  0.14288   -2.316          -0.20463   0.14363  -1.425
insageY   0.56995  0.12463    4.573          -0.38022   0.19435  -1.956
```

Comment: Are they interchangeable? One assumes you chose to try the random-effects model for a reason related to iid?

Comment: I fitted my claims data using a Classical Poisson regression model and then used the geographical area as a random effect and obtained the above results. @ charles

Comment: Ok. if you don't have a strong pre-data assumption that there should be clustering you could do an LR test comparing the two models to estimate if the random effect improves model fit. Mathematically this is painful. Not sure how {R} deals with those issues. Most stats packages will provide you with some attempt at an estimate (usually conservative).

Comment: Bootstrapping would be a great way to do @charles tests if you have the data volume to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Most real-life data is overdispersed compared to the Poisson distribution. This occurs whenever the units considered differ in some - usually multiple - way(s) that cannot all be accounted for as covariates and that may somehow influence event rates without it being clear whether you would expect one unit to have a higher or lower event rate (if that were clear a covariate adjustment would be better). As a result it is very often appropriate to use a model that takes this into account either with a random effect or with a random effect that is integrated out to give e.g. a negative binomial regression model = Poisson with gamma random effect (in addition to adjustment for known covariates, as well as offsets such as log(time at risk)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hausman test, with which you test the difference between the estimated coefficients obtained with the (pooled or fixed-effect) Poisson model and the random-effect Poisson model.